# Regex for Google Analytics Goal

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I've searched all the other Regex on Google Analytics questions but I can't use the answers as this is pretty specific to my problem.

I want to set a destination URL goal but use Regex to flag it as a goal IF string includes /general/

I basically want to track everyone in GA who goes to a Vehicle Detail Page but /general/ brings them to a Search Results Page.

so in other words

/used-cars/general is not correct

/used-cars/citreon/ is correct

/used-cars/TOYOTA/ is correct

Basically, any other car maker is correct after /used-cars/ regardless if it is capitalized or not.

Thanks in advance, everyone.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far so we can help. Post your code.

Comment: so far, I have tried /used-cars/(citreon|TOYOTA|RENAULT|VOLKSWAGEN|VAUXHALL|HONDA|BMW|NISSAN|PEUGEOT|DS|FORD|HYUNDAI|INFINITI|MERCEDES-BENZ|MITSUBISHI)/

Comment: Try `used-cars\/(?!general)\w+` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/r4ZNO9/1)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is on the right path, but you should escape any special characters. Try the below instead:

`/used\-cars/(citreon|TOYOTA|RENAULT|VOLKSWAGEN|VAUXHALL|HONDA|BMW|NISSAN|PEUGEOT|DS|FORD|HYUNDAI|INFINITI|MERCEDES\-BENZ|MITSUBISHI)/`